# displaying float in android without adding trailing zero

Tags: android, string

I've got a series of float numbers; I want to display them as they are;
but while I use `String.getValueOf` .0 will be added to my numbers
ie 10 is shows as 10.0
what should i do to prevent this mess ?

Comment: Don't use a float if you don't want the decimal place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if(stringVariable.endsWith(".0")) stringVariable = stringVariable.replace(".0" , "");
```

This way it will remove .0 only if the string ends with .0

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get this Error : The method endsWith(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the quotation marks `".0"`

Answer (score 1):

You can change from float to int using Math.round()

Answer (score 0):

using something like sprintf would do it

```
String.format("%.0f", value);
```

Comment: can u elaborate this with an example ; let say we have 5.65656565 in an array.

Comment: %.0f means display a float with nothing after the .  You could say %.2f if you wanted to show 2 decimal places for example.

Comment: what if I dont know that my string is 0 or 0.121212 ; applying this doesnt give me 0.00 ?

Comment: Dear 0xFADE ! can you help me on this ? when I apply what you said with the accepted answer of my question; everything is right but I get 10.00 ; how do i remove those 00 ?

Comment: 0.5 in such case will be displayed as 1